# Separating CodeIgniter config file Git for publishing publically

Tags: php, git, codeigniter, configuration, github

I am about to start a CodeIgniter based project and plan on using Git as our DVCS. I will be working with a few other developers, and the central (origin) server is privately hosted. But I also want to open source it and publish the code to Github later.

My question is, is there a way to separate the config file(s) in Git, so that the private information in the config file is not sent to the Github remote but is to origin and other peers.

Another question is could we use a similar solution for having local development config files and a server one for production?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create the files `config.php.sample` and `database.php.sample` that each of your developers will use that has a placeholder for the passwords and other sensitive information.   Add `config.php` and `database.php` to your `.gitignore`

The first time you deploy to the production site, you'll create the `config.php` and `database.php` files.   Subsequent pushes won't overwrite `config.php` and `database.php` since they're not included in the git repository.

Comment: I have decided to use this system with an additional README to explain it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Codeigniter has some support for environments (Development, Production, etc).
Refer to official documentation , [CodeIgniter Environments](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/environments.html).

Regarding config files, you can use `.gitignore`

http://progit.org/book/ch2-2.html

Edit:
Since you have used `github` tag in the question; Github now has an option to add `.gitignore` file (they have a codeigniter template too )

Answer (score 0):

You should use a deployment tool to set the config file when deploying your application to the destination system.

`capistrano` with `railsless-deploy` is a good option