# How to keep CodIgniter application and config in their own in git repos?

Tags: php, git, codeigniter, github, bitbucket

Can anybody tell me what kind of workflow should I follow to keep my application source and configuration tracked in Git? I want to keep my config separate from my source is because there is one config for development, another for production enviroment and, and a third for local testing.

Comment: I don't think your config files should ever be versioned in GitHub.  Find some other way to accomplish what you want.

Comment: You should have the real config file ignored in your git-repo and just have a config example (append something like `-example.php` on the file), without any sensitive information in the git repo. Then any developer/environment can copy that config, add the missing/environment specific information without any problems.

Comment: Is there any other way? why I want this in tracking is because when anything has been added in the config the corresponding changes will be received by team memebers in their pull request

Comment: I am concern about variables, constants, autoload, changes in config directory not actually about database.php

Answer (score 2):

It's not unheard of to have a repo just for configuration files (just make sure that git repo does **NOT HAVE PUBLIC ACCESS** (so, not github unless you have private repos enabled). You end up with a repo for code, and a repo for configuration files, sometimes maintained by a different team (say, the deployment team).

The problem you have is that as far as I'm aware, git doesn't particularly like having multiple repos at the same level.

I don't know anything about CI, but I think it stores its configuration files in `application/config`.

Two options I can think of:

- You can convert all `application/config` to a git repo and gitignore that folder from the main development repo.
- If converting the whole folder into a repo is not feasible (say, some of the configuration files actually belong to the application repo), maintain a separate repo folder somewhere else in the system and symlink your necessary configuration files to `application/config` (and gitignore those symlinks in your code repo)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use separate Git repositories. CodeIgniter supports the idea of [environments](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/environments.html):

> Developers often desire different system behavior depending on whether an application is running in a development or production environment. For example, verbose error output is something that would be useful while developing an application, but it may also pose a security issue when "live".
>
> ### The ENVIRONMENT Constant
>
> By default, CodeIgniter comes with the environment constant set to use the value provided in `$_SERVER['CI_ENV']`, otherwise defaults to 'development'.

Set the `CI_ENV` environment variable for each server process to tell CodeIgniter which environment you're on. Depending on your stack this could involve using Apache's [`SetEnv`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_env.html#setenv), a shell `export`, or other mechanism.

Then you can set up [environment-specific configuration files](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/config.html#environments):

> To create an environment-specific configuration file, create or copy a configuration file in application/config/{ENVIRONMENT}/{FILENAME}.php
>
> For example, to create a production-only config.php, you would:
>
> 1. Create the directory application/config/production/
> 2. Copy your existing config.php into the above directory
> 3. Edit application/config/production/config.php so it contains your production settings
>
> When you set the ENVIRONMENT constant to ‘production’, the settings for your new production-only config.php will be loaded.

Additionally, you may want to load certain settings directly from the environment, as described by the [The Twelve-Factor App](https://12factor.net/config). (This isn't something that I've seen people do with CodeIgniter before, but it's a useful idea in general.)

For example, it might make sense to keep API keys or database connection information out of your config files, or to leave development-friendly values in your config files and override them with values loaded from environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

[An answer from a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10401249/1482015) will help you, it is answer by SO user @dwilkins.
Mr dwikins answer is simple, clear and effective. He suggest gitignore any conf you don't want, but remember to create "conf.sample" sample file.
Mr @alex-stuckey comment to add README file to guide other team member to use the "sample" file.

Answer (score -2):

The following workflow was used back when i was a system administrator and we made scripts that depended on a config preset.
Basically, the main script was always the same, and the script's actions would depend on a config file that would hang from the master branch as so:

Master

|----Script.py

|----config_template.cfg

From Master we would take a branch that looked like so

Mimulation_machine

|----Script.py

|----simulation.cfg-------------->this was the modified config file

The workflow was to switch to master and create a new branch, that would eventually hold the configuration files. It is important that the branches would never merge back to master though. This may not be the best answer nor the most correct but it worked, and allowed us to switch to different configurations with a simple checkout.

Mind you that is an oversimplified verion of what we really had going on, we had a complex structure made out of gitignores and so.